# A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object?

Tags: c++

I have this simple code where two inner classes are depending on each other. I can't call object's `functionB()` inside of `functionC()` although as you can see I have created a pointer to an object of `ClassB` and even instantiated the object yet I still get the error that I need to call the function from an object. I was wondering what exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA() { object = new ClassB(); };
    ~ClassA();
    void functionA() {  };
private:
    class ClassB
    {
    public:
        void functionB() { std::cout << "Function B"; };
    };
    class ClassC
    {
    public:
        void functionC() {
            std::cout << "Fuction C";
            object->functionB();
        }; //Error here
    };
    ClassB* object;
    ClassC* object1;
};
```

Comment: What exact error message are you getting?

Comment: A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Answer (score 5):

C++ simply does not capture its "parent" instance, as e.g. Java does. In the nested ClassB and ClassC you need an explicit back-reference to ClassA:

```
class ClassA {
public:
    ClassA() : object(new ClassB(*this)) {}
    ~ClassA() { delete this->object; }
private:
    class ClassB {
        classA &parent;
    public:
        ClassB(classA &parent) : parent(parent) {}
    };
    ClassB *object;
};
```

But why do you allocate ClassB in here dynamically? This is easier to read and understand and less error prone:

```
class ClassA {
public:
    ClassA() : object(*this) {}
    ~ClassA() {}
private:
    class ClassB {
        classA &parent;
    public:
        ClassB(classA &parent) : parent(parent) {}
    };
    ClassB object;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed it. That's what I get for starting with java I guess.

Comment: Hehe, Java does a lot implict magic behind the scenes. C++ tends to be more explicit. What is better is a matter of taste I guess.

Comment: I had it first without the pointers and then when I got the error, I decided to change to it pointers thinking it would work.

Answer (score 3):

I would say, the error text is misleading. But in essence it means that there is no way to access parent **object** from child **object**, unless parent object is specifically captured in child's member.

The code has a big problem with the incorrect management of pointers (see rule of 5), but since I take this is for illustration only, I won't focus on it.

Comment: Indeed the error is a bit misleading. Thanks for you help.

Comment: It's exactly like you said only for illustration purposes.